# Windows update never finishes checking for updates on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have 2 Dell Optiplex GX620 PCs. Both have Windows 7 Home Premium. When checking for updates, both systems needed the update service updated before showing check for updates button. Once that was done, when I click check for updates, they never finish. The progress bar just keeps going.
1 PC is a fresh install, the other has been running for a while.
I have tried the Windows Update Automated Troubleshooter available from Microsoft with no success on either PC.
I do not see any update related errors in the event log and no error is ever displayed. (I have waited an hour on both)
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: download and install the Update KB3050265 from downloadcenter and look if this is faster now

Comment: KB3050265 "This issue has the greatest effect on computers that have a small amount of physical memory." I have tried it on several systems and has no effect on the speed of Windows update scanning the system, on a reinstall of Windows 7 it takes an average of 1-1.5 hours for windows update to populate the page with updates.